# How can we deactivate our previous apk on new Google Play console look?

Tags: android, google-play

I uploaded my apk with incremental version code In previous play console when we upload the apk the last submitted apk will automatically unpublished now this time i am getting in production two apks how can i deactivate my previous apk and it is also giving me some rollout message of 10% what is meant by that ...Kindly guide me how to deactivate my previous apk after uploading my new apk

[image: see image description here]

Answer (score 1):

Click create release and there you will see deactivate for the previous APKs.

Answer (score 0):

> If you face this problem in december 2021

> when you upload the .abb file. their is included and not included
> section .in included section the last aab is
> there.. their is 3 dot on last abb file click on it then their is option "remove app
> bundle just click on it.

Answer (score -1):

look at the right side from your console there is 3 dot
click on it and now you got unpublish app.

Answer (score -1):

In order to unpublish your app, please click on Store presence -> Pricing & distribution -> App availability, and then select 'Unpublish'.

Comment: deactivate and unpublish are different.

Answer (score -1):

Unpublish for sharing the new method on 2021.In the setup section in the release section that exists in the left menu, there is an advanced settings section that you can open and process there.

Comment: This does not really help. Could you please give more instructions or details how to do it? like screenshots.